# How to query firebase items with specific reference type

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I have a parent collection `categories` and it child collection `directories`
`Directories` connected with `Categories` via `Category` property

[image]

I want to query all directories with category equal to `level`

```
this.firestore
      .collection<any>('directories', ref => ref.where('categories', '==', 'levels'))
      .get()
      .pipe(
        map(x => {
          const out: [] = [];
          x.forEach(y => {
            out.push(y.data());
          });
          return out;
        })
      );
```

I am getting an empty array in return. How would you fix that?

**UPDATE** based on the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54862990/2926340) provided by @renaud-tarnec:

```
const categoryDocRef = this.firestore.doc('categories/levels');
this.firestore
      .collection<any>('directories', ref => ref.where('categories', '==', categoryDocRef))
      .get()
      .pipe(
        map(x => {
          const out: [] = [];
          x.forEach(y => {
            out.push(y.data());
          });
          return out;
        })
      );
```

Now having an error `core.js:15713 ERROR Error: Function Query.where() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: a custom AngularFirestoreDocument object`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use the [DocumentReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference) data type in a query, you have to build a DocumentReference and use it in your query, as follows (in "standard" JavaScript):

```
        const categoryDocRef = firebase.firestore().doc('categories/levels');

        firebase.firestore().collection("directories").where("parent", "==", categoryDocRef)
        .get()
        .then(function(querySnapshot) {
           querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
              console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
           });
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
           console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
        });
```

I've made the assumption that the documents containing the field `parent` (which , in turn, contains the `DocumentReference` type data) are in a collection named `directories`.

---

**UPDATE: It appears that the following won't work with angularFire2, see the comments**

So, if I am not mistaking, this would be done as follow in angular, based on the code of your question:

```
const categoryDocRef = this.firestore.doc('categories/levels');

this.firestore
      .collection<any>('directories', ref => ref.where('parent', '==', categoryDocRef))
      .get()
      ...
```

Comment: just updated the question, had a wrong img. However now getting an error `ERROR Error: Function Query.where() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: a custom AngularFirestoreDocument object` trying to implement your solution

Comment: I have the feeling that angularFire does not accept DocumentReferences in Queries. You might have to switch to more standard JavaScript. (Sorry I cannot help anymore here, I am using Vue.js on my side :-) )

Comment: yeah had to fallback to firebase via `firestore.firestore.collection('categories').doc(...)` and `firestore.firestore.collection('directories').where(....)`